# Active vs inactive bitcoin nodes

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-core-development

The protocol documentation states "The typical presumption is that a node is likely to be active if it has been sending a message within the last three hours."

Does this mean any message coming from the node? or a specific message?

Also, when are unsolicited addr messages sent out from a node? I know of one scenario where if a node decides to listen to incoming connections it sends out an addr message with its info in it.

Does a node send addr messages without receiving a getaddr, and what is the frequency of these messages?